# Will dataReader remain null causing "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed "?

Tags: asp.net, data-access-layer

I wrote this method so that I dont have to write opening connection etc. code everytime.

```
 public static bool TryExecuteReader(string commandText,string functionNameForLogging, string errorText, out SqlDataReader dataReader)
        {
            bool success = false;
            dataReader = null;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = SqlUtilities.CreateSqlConnection())
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = commandText;
                    dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);                    
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SqlUtilities.LogError(functionNameForLogging,ex.Message,-1);
            }

            return success;
        }
```

I thought this should work fine, but lately I am getting error "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed ". Now I am not sure why this error is occuring. But this seemed like the most likely reason. Its been a while so I cannot say for sure whether the error is caused by this way. does the datareader remain null once the using block is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the using block ends the datareader is closed.
So any attempt to read data out of the reader will throw an exception.
Remember the datareader is using a db connection.  When the connection is closed (after your using statement) that will call Dispose on the SQLConnection in turn making the SqlDataReader nothing / null.

Put your code to making the connection outside of the using statement like so.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = SqlUtilities.CreateSqlConnection()
using(SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
 {
  sqlCommand.CommandText = commandText; 
  dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader   (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);                     
 }
conn.Open();
success=true;
```

Because you have specified:

`CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`

When you executed your command object the minute you close your data reader the connection to the database will also be closed.

You could if you wanted have your function return a datareader instead of a boolean.  It really depends on your preference.  But if you return a datareader you could check with `HasRows` or `Read` methods.  You could then wrap the datareader in a using statement for instance:

```
using (SqlDataReader myDataReader = GetMyDataReader())
 {
   //do something with the reader
 }
```

At the end of the using statement for `myDataReader` `.Dispose()` will be called automatically.  Since you called `.ExecuteReader()` inside of `GetMyDataReader()` with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` then disposing of the reader will also close your db connection.

Comment: But the dataReader was declared outside the using block. Rather it was declared outside and passed to this method.

Comment: @sassyboy - that doesn't matter because you are using the connection sqlConnection in your command object.  And your command object which uses your sqlConnection object is used to `.ExecuteReader`.  So that means your datareader is using your sqlConnection object.  So what happens is immediately after the using statement the sqlConnection object is disposed of, which means your command object is done with and your data reader is done with.

Answer (score 1):

Read the post : [ExecuteReader with CommanBehavior ( automatically close connection after reading data)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/executereader-with-commanbehavior.html)

You are getting an error because you are closing the connection when using the `USING` block.

Instead of this set command behavior

- **CommandBehavior.CloseConnection**

  When you pass above values as argument to ExecuteReader

  1. there is no need to close connection explicitly connection get close when you close your reader.

     //No need to close connection you just have to write
     reader.Close();
  2. It usefull when you pass reader to another method for processing data.